How to program application code by using custom bootloader in ATmega324P
I'm trying to create a bootloader for ATmega324P and encountering some issues. First, I attempted to view the hex code of the application (Blink LED) as follows:

Then, I saved the hex code into an array within the bootloader code and programmed it at address 0x00D0 like this:
void send_data_to_flash()
{
    unsigned char data1[] = {0x11, 0xe0, 0xa0, 0xe0, 0xb1, 0xe0, 0xe2, 0xe7, 0xf1, 0xe0, 0x02, 0xc0, 0x05, 0x90, 0x0d, 0x92,
                             0xa4, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x07, 0xd9, 0xf7, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x84, 0xb1, 0x80, 0x62, 0x84, 0xb9, 0x8a, 0xb1,
                             0x8f, 0x7e, 0x8a, 0xb9, 0x8b, 0xb1, 0x80, 0x61, 0x8b, 0xb9, 0x08, 0x95, 0x95, 0xb1, 0x80, 0xe2, 0x89, 0x27,
                             0x85, 0xb9, 0x08, 0x95, 0xcf, 0x93, 0xdf, 0x93, 0xcd, 0xb7, 0xde, 0xb7, 0x63, 0x97, 0x0f, 0xb6, 0xf8, 0x94,
                             0xde, 0xbf, 0x0f, 0xbe, 0xcd, 0xbf, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x0d, 0x00, 0x80, 0xe8, 0x95, 0xe2, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x4b, 0x00,
                             0x83, 0xe1, 0xe0, 0xe0, 0xf1, 0xe0, 0xde, 0x01, 0x11, 0x96, 0x01, 0x90, 0x0d, 0x92, 0x8a, 0x95, 0xe1, 0xf7,
                             0x63, 0xe1, 0x70, 0xe0, 0xce, 0x01, 0x01, 0x96, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x83, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x17, 0x00, 0x2f, 0xef,
                             0x81, 0xee, 0x94, 0xe0, 0x21, 0x50, 0x80, 0x40, 0x90, 0x40, 0xe1, 0xf7, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf4, 0xcf,
                             0x81, 0xe0, 0x08, 0x95, 0x80, 0xe0, 0x08, 0x95, 0xcf, 0x93, 0xdf, 0x93, 0xec, 0x01, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x49, 0x00,
                             0x88, 0x23, 0x21, 0xf0, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x47, 0x00, 0x81, 0x11, 0x29, 0xc0, 0xce, 0x01, 0xa0, 0xe0, 0xb0, 0xe0,
                             0x88, 0x0f, 0x99, 0x1f, 0xaa, 0x1f, 0xbb, 0x1f, 0x88, 0x0f, 0x99, 0x1f, 0xaa, 0x1f, 0xbb, 0x1f, 0x9c, 0x01,
                             0xad, 0x01, 0x22, 0x0f, 0x33, 0x1f, 0x44, 0x1f, 0x55, 0x1f, 0x22, 0x0f, 0x33, 0x1f, 0x44, 0x1f, 0x55, 0x1f,
                             0x60, 0xe0, 0x74, 0xe2, 0x84, 0xef, 0x90, 0xe0, 0x0e, 0x94, 0x97, 0x00, 0x21, 0x50, 0x31, 0x09, 0x30, 0x93,
                             0xc5, 0x00, 0x20, 0x93, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x88, 0xe1, 0x80, 0x93, 0xc1, 0x00, 0x86, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x93, 0xc2, 0x00,
                             0x80, 0xe0, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x81, 0xe0};
    unsigned char data2[] = {0xdf, 0x91, 0xcf, 0x91, 0x08, 0x95, 0xac, 0x01, 0x20, 0xe0, 0x30, 0xe0, 0x0c, 0xc0, 0x90, 0x91, 0xc0,
                             0x00, 0x95, 0xff, 0xfc, 0xcf, 0xfa, 0x01, 0xe2, 0x0f, 0xf3, 0x1f, 0x90, 0x81, 0x90, 0x93, 0xc6, 0x00, 0x2f,
                             0x5f, 0x3f, 0x4f, 0x26, 0x17, 0x37, 0x07, 0x88, 0xf3, 0x08, 0x95, 0xa1, 0xe2, 0x1a, 0x2e, 0xaa, 0x1b, 0xbb,
                             0x1b, 0xfd, 0x01, 0x0d, 0xc0, 0xaa, 0x1f, 0xbb, 0x1f, 0xee, 0x1f, 0xff, 0x1f, 0xa2, 0x17, 0xb3, 0x07, 0xe4,
                             0x07, 0xf5, 0x07, 0x20, 0xf0, 0xa2, 0x1b, 0xb3, 0x0b, 0xe4, 0x0b, 0xf5, 0x0b, 0x66, 0x1f, 0x77, 0x1f, 0x88,
                             0x1f, 0x99, 0x1f, 0x1a, 0x94, 0x69, 0xf7, 0x60, 0x95, 0x70, 0x95, 0x80, 0x95, 0x90, 0x95, 0x9b, 0x01, 0xac,
                             0x01, 0xbd, 0x01, 0xcf, 0x01, 0x08, 0x95, 0x52, 0x45, 0x53, 0x45, 0x54, 0x20, 0x41, 0x50, 0x50, 0x4c, 0x49,
                             0x43, 0x41, 0x54, 0x49, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00};
    flash_write_data(ADDRESS_F_DATA, data1, sizeof(data1));
    flash_write_data(ADDRESS_F_DATA + sizeof(data1), data2, sizeof(data2));
}

Moving to application
        //Move to Application address
        if (!(PIND & (1 << PIND4))) //check pressing button
        {
            __asm__ volatile("jmp 0x00D0");
        }

But it did not work as i expected. It seems like it erases all of things that i put in 0x00D0(application location) after jumping. I pretty sure that my write flash function is work well.
Could you guys tell me the reasons why it not happen?

Why are you trying to make your own bootloader? Some academic research? Otherwise just use optiboot from MightyCore - there is also directory with compiled hex files for almost any possibility you might want (cpu freq + usart + baud rate).

How did you verify that the write works? I think it doesn't work. For example, how do you solve the writing of an incomplete page?

I read those page via UART before i move to application.
When i move to application i also read it like in boot mode, but it just 0xFF for those page @@

@KIIV 'Some academic research' yah, it is

Don't test it with UART. Simply read FLASH using ISP after saving via bootloader. I don't understand what you mean by moving to the application. It looks like you can delete the page, but you can't write data to it.

What is flash_write_data? What is ADDRESS_F_DATA? Why jmp at 0x00D0, not 0x0000, where the program should be located?
